# GitHub Actions how to deploy Pyvis html file to Github Pages

Tags: python, github, pyvis

I want to deploy python pyvis app to github pages with actions and workflow, pyvis is the only pip package i use in it

I tried asking gpt and it showed something not related.

here are network settings that i use

```
network = Network(directed=True, height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white")
...
network.set_edge_smooth('dynamic')
network.toggle_physics(True)
network.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
network.barnes_hut(gravity=-3000)
network.show("graph.html", local=True, notebook=False)
```

whole code can be found on my repo: https://github.com/wiktormalyska/CannibalMissionaryProblemGraph

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages does not run any backend. If you try to set up a website on github, you cannot implement things that are required to run in the backend. You‘ll only be able to host static sites using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Please read more about GitHub Pages here:
https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#about-github-pages